# What is the correct usage of next.js app and pages directories?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, sitemap

I'm working on next.js 13 project which uses /pages directory instead of /app, I just added app directory to use its new features for dynamic sitemap rendering and only for that

is this acceptable practice ? example [example usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GOmG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the next docs, using app router alongside pages router is possible (for backward compatibility purposes) but you better use one router only.